# How to check if BitmapImage created by Uri is actually an image?

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, bitmapimage

my application receives dragged and dropped links from Internet and tries to create image from supplied link.

Code looks like this.

```
if (link.StartsWith("http"))
{
    try
    {
        itemImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(link));
        if (itemImage.Source != null)
        {
            if (itemImage.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                ShowImage();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception){}
}
```

It handles it's job quite well to the moment when provided link contain path to image.
If path is for example "https://stackoverflow.com/" program assumes that this link provides image too, so it's running code inside of if condition (imageSource != null) and shows empty image.

However while pressing button to save that invalid "image" and checking if Source isn't really null program runs ShowNameError method (with assumption that name is set properly)

```
if (itemImage.Source == null || name == string.Empty)
{
    ShowNameError("Set name or/and image of item first");
    return;
}
```

In other words - ImageSource isn't null in first condition, but in second it is null, which doesn't make sense because nowhere in code ImageSource is manipulated anymore.

And since that magic tricks are happening, I'm asking you how to check if BitmapImage created by Uri IS actually an image?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking here. If `itemImage.Source` is once non-null it won't magically become null later. Anyway, you should be aware that images from remote URLs are lazily loaded by default. There are events like `BitmapImage.DownloadCompleted` and `BitmapImage.DownloadFailed` which you may attach handlers to.

Comment: Checking `if (itemImage.Source != null)` is redundant anyway, because either there is a newly created BitmapImage assigned to Source, or an exception thrown by the BitmapImage  constructor. The if condition is always true when reached.

Comment: Handling DownloadCompleted event worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether the BitmapImage has immediately loaded the bitmap or not. If the `IsDownloading` property is true, attach a handler for the `DownloadCompleted` and optionally also the `DownloadFailed` event:

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(link));

if (image.IsDownloading)
{
    image.DownloadCompleted += (s, e) => ShowImage(image);
}
else
{
    ShowImage(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use magic bytes to 'see' if the image is actually a known image format. You can see a full list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

For example, a PNG always starts with `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A`. You could download the binary data and check that binary result against the magic bytes for PNG, JPG, BMP, etc. If it matches, you will probably be safe.

Comment: OP should get an exception when decoding fails. This may happen immediately, e.g. when a local image file is loaded, or later, when an image loaded from a remote URL image is first shown.

Comment: I think you nailed the problem in your comment: downloading is probably delayed, which causes the (failing) image to be empty. First downloading and checking solves that, as suggested.

Comment: I agree, now it works as it should work, thank you for answers.